# Twitter Fetcher

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have tried my hardest to get Twitter Fetcher (http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/#sthash.0H0MQghJ.dpbs) to work and I can't. Can someone please tell me **exactly** how to apply it?

I've got a standard HTML5 page that I want to add this to. I've added the js file to the head. I've got my ID Twitter widget and added it to this, twitterFetcher.fetch('345170787868762112', 'twitterFeed', 1, true); (between script tags).

Now, where does that exactly go? 'twitterFeed' is the div that I want the tweets displayed in. I've tried this for nearly 2 hours now and nothing is happening. If someone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: I've got it working now. It only work when on a live site.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow up to this post - the reason for it working on the live site but not locally is due to the fact many computer browsers block JavaScript execution when running from file:// instead of http://. Always ensure you are running from a webserver eg via localhost if you want to test locally. You could use Apache to do this for instance. :-)